Как работать с TouchDelegateInfoCompat в accessibility service?
Я никогда не работала с TouchDelegateInfo и совсем его понимаю.
Я искала способы работы с ним в интернете но там только со стороны приложения а не accessibility service:(

Может ли кто-то объяснить?
P.s.
Вот ссылка: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/view/accessibility/AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat.TouchDelegateInfoCompat
За ранее спасибо)

